# What's the most efficient way to generate this report?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Given a table (daily_sales) with say 100k rows of the following data/columns:

```
id    rep   sales  date  
1     a     123    12/15/2011  
2     b     153    12/15/2011  
3     a      11    12/14/2011  
4     a     300    12/13/2011  
5     a     120    12/12/2011  
6     b     161    11/15/2011  
7     a       3    11/14/2011  
8     c      13    11/14/2011  
9     c      44    11/13/2011
```

What would be the most efficient way to write a report (completely in SQL) showing the two most recent entries (rep, sales, date) for each name, so the output would be:

```
a  123  12/15/2011  
a   11  12/14/2011  
b  153  12/15/2011  
b  161  11/15/2011  
c   13  11/14/2011  
c   44  11/13/2011
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to see all answers using standard SQL or vendor-specific, but lets say mysql (I'll add that as a tag to the question too if I can)

Comment: what if there are only ONE entry for a 'name'?

Comment: Whats the primary Key on your table?  My first thoughts would be to use a union between 2 queries, one to pick out the max (straight forward) and union that to a second query that has the second most recent date.  Second is a lil more complicated, you'd select the max trans_date where not in a list of ID's from the first query...which is why I'd need an ID column

Comment: @daryn Sure, but the "most-efficient" solution will depend on what tools are available.

Comment: @Tewlfth that's definitely one approach. feel free to assume a primary key column 'id' (i'll edit question).

Comment: @djacobson very true. If you know of any vendor-specific awesomely efficient solutions, I'd love to see those too.

Comment: Why must it be so efficient? It will take ten hours to read the output! (I am a fast reader)

Comment: @wildplasser: Not if there are only a few different names.

Comment: @daryn - lil late for my answer now, but using reserved words like name,value,date as column names...even if just an example...makes this extremely hard to program for you.

Comment: Sorry for the bad column names and lack of table names in the example - this was completely made up.

Comment: @ypercube: which makes me remember that Postgres sometimes has a special node in the queryplan for find-best-n. But I forgot how it was activated. My guess is that the window-functions are not that fast, because they are relatively young, and there is a lots of semantics involved (the "aggregate" functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, explained in **[@Quassnoi's blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/06/advanced-row-sampling/)**, an index on `(name, date)` and using this:

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  name,
                COALESCE(
                (
                SELECT  date
                FROM    tableX ti
                WHERE   ti.name = dto.name
                ORDER BY
                        ti.name, ti.date DESC
                LIMIT 1 
                OFFSET 1                      --- this is set to 2-1 
                ), CAST('1000-01-01' AS DATE)) AS mdate
        FROM    (
                SELECT  DISTINCT name
                FROM    tableX dt
                ) dto
        ) tg
        , tableX t
WHERE   t.name >= tg.name
  AND   t.name <= tg.name
  AND   t.date >= tg.mdate
```

Comment: Line -5. Renamed it to `tg` as `to` is reserved.

Comment: i was just blind! anyhow the rename was probably a good idea ;-)

Answer (score 2):

FYI, your example is using mostly reserved words and makes it horrid for us to attempt to program against.  If you've got the real table columns, gives those to us.  This is postgres:

```
select name,value, max(date)
from the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us
group by 1,2
```

That'll give you a list of first name,value,max(date)...though I gotta ask why give us a column called value if it doesn't change in the example?

Lets say you do have an id column...we'll be consistent with your scheme and call it 'ID'...

```
 select b.id from
(select name,value, max(date) date
from the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us
group by 1,2) a
inner join the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us b on a.name=b.name and a.value=b.value and a.date = b.date
```

This gives a list of all ID's that are the max...put it together:

```
select name,value, max(date)
from the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us
group by 1,2
```

union all

```
select name,value, max(date)
from the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us
where id not in
(select b.id from
(select name,value, max(date) date
from the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us
group by 1,2) a
inner join the_table_name_you_neglect_to_give_us b on a.name=b.name and a.value=b.value      and a.date = b.date)
```

Hoping my syntax is right...should be close at any rate.  I'd put a bracket around that entire thing then select * from (above query) order by name...gives you the order you want.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the bad names/missing info/misleading data.  "value" column was meant to be arbitrary numbers

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you mean.. Then this MIGHT be helpful:

```sql
SELECT main.name, main.value, main.date 
FROM tablename AS main
LEFT OUTER JOIN tablename AS ctr
    ON main.name = ctr.rname
    AND main.date <= ctr.rdate
GROUP BY main.name, main.date
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
ORDER BY main.name ASC, main.date DESC
```

I know the SQL is shorter than the other posts, but just give it a try first..

Comment: sorry, i should have put some random numbers in there. "value" isn't meant to be consistent.

Comment: Can you try? I modified my post